# Conditional calculating Maximum value in the column

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have the following table:

```
Class  x2  x3  x4
  A    14  45  53 
  A     8  18  17
  A    16  49  20
  B    78  21  48 
  B     8  18   5
```

I need for each "Class" (A and B) find the maximum value in column "X3", keep that row and delete other rows.

The output should be in format like:

```
Class  x2  x3  x4
  A    14  49  20
  B    78  21  48
```

Please, ask me questions if something unclear in my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What is you expected result in cases of ties? i.e. if in colum x3 the first and the third entry were both 49?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R approach could be:

```
mydf[as.logical(with(mydf, ave(x3, Class, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))), ]
#   Class x2 x3 x4
# 3     A 16 49 20
# 4     B 78 21 48
```

However, note that if there are multiple values tied for `max`, it would return multiple rows for that group.

---

Here's a possible "data.table" approach:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(as.data.table(mydf), Class, x3)[, tail(.SD, 1), by = Class]
#    Class x2 x3 x4
# 1:     A 16 49 20
# 2:     B 78 21 48
```

Comment: Considering tied max values is great. Very thoughtful. +1 :)

Comment: @jazzurro, but the question doesn't provide enough information to say whether this is desirable or not :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way using `dplyr` would be:

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>%
    #For each Class
    group_by(Class) %>%
    # Sort rows in descending way using x3: you get the max x3 value on top
    # for each group
    arrange(desc(x3)) %>%
    # Select the first row for each Class
    slice(1)

#  Class x2 x3 x4
#1     A 16 49 20
#2     B 78 21 48
```

**EDIT**
Given @Ananda's tie-values consideration and his suggestion in coments,
you could do something like this as well. But, @Richard Acriven's idea is
the way to go, if there are ties.

```
# Data
foo2 <- structure(list(Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), x2 = c(14L, 8L, 16L, 78L, 8L), x3 = c(49L, 
18L, 49L, 21L, 18L), x4 = c(53L, 17L, 20L, 48L, 5L)), .Names = c("Class", 
"x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

#  Class x2 x3 x4
#1     A 14 49 53
#2     A  8 18 17
#3     A 16 49 20
#4     B 78 21 48
#5     B  8 18  5  

foo2 %>% 
   group_by(Class) %>% 
   mutate(Rank = dense_rank(desc(x3))) %>%
   filter(Rank == 1)

#  Class x2 x3 x4 Rank
#1     A 14 49 53    1
#2     A 16 49 20    1
#3     B 78 21 48    1
```

Comment: +1. I don't use "dplyr" much, but `slice` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @AnandaMahto If `slice` can take ties, that would be sweet.

Comment: "dplyr" has pretty good `rank` options that could be useful here.

Comment: @AnandaMahto True that! `dense_rank` I think. Let me play with it. :)

Comment: Maybe something like `foo2 %>% group_by(Class) %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(desc(x3))) %>% filter(Rank == 1)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes, that's it. :-) I was doing other things. Thanks for your another generous help. splitstackshape is working well with the tentative solution, by the way.

Comment: If you want to allow multiple rows in cases of ties, I would rather just do `foo2 %>% group_by(Class) %>% mutate(x3 == max(x3))`

Comment: @beginneR Thank you of your message. Yes, that is what Richard has here. He used `filter`. I totally agree with you.

Comment: I didn't see Richards answer first.

Comment: Just one last thing, if you use `dense_rank` as you do in your second solution, you could avoid the mutate and use `dense_rank` right in the filter `foo2 %>% group_by(Class) %>% filter(dense_rank(desc(x3)) == 1)`. You can do the same inside `group_by` when you need to create a new column on which to group the data.

Comment: @beginneR Yes, that is another way to go. Thank you very much for your suggestion. This become a good chance to revise `dplyr` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `dplyr` answer for the lot

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Class) %>% filter(x3 == max(x3))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
# Groups: Class
# 
#   Class x2 x3 x4
# 1     A 16 49 20
# 2     B 78 21 48
```

Which could also be

```
group_by(df, Class) %>% filter(x3 == max(x3))
```

Comment: In this way, you don't need `dense_rank`. Your first dplyr answer? +1 :)

Comment: My second.  The first one got down-voted and I deleted it.  Haha. I've decided to learn to use `dplyr` more.  I really like this piping stuff.  And the code is really clean.

Comment: We are all like that, aren't we? Make mistakes and learn more! I misread a question related to strings the other day and got downvoted; I immediately apologised and deleted my answer.

Comment: You may already have this material. If not, this will be pretty useful for dplyr. I have been using this as a reference all the time. Check [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8qnluwmuieicxc/AACsepZJvULCKkbIxK9KP-6Ea/dplyr-tutorial.pdf?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(ddf, ddf$Class), function(x) tail(x[order(x$x3),],1)))
  Class x2 x3 x4
A     A 16 49 20
B     B 78 21 48
```