# R find max value in a column for which there are no values in corresponding columns

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

I would like to know how I find the last row which has no value for D or L as I want to set this as the x axis plot limit for a looped histogram.
I needs to be the rowname value (here it actually corresponds to a length) which is the highest for which there were any values), there could be other lengths which also have 0 values (i.e. like 51 in this df) but I want the length which has no other lengths following it with values (in this df = 60).

```
> t4
           D         L
5    0.00000   0.00000
6    0.00000   0.00000
7    0.00000   0.00000
8    0.00000   0.00000
9    0.00000   0.00000
10   2.83726   0.28757
11   1.84987   0.28757
12   5.03907   0.00000
13   9.88651   0.00000
14  17.70186   0.00000
15  17.79735   0.00000
16  22.11712   0.00000
17  15.28029   0.00000
18  18.78395   0.20838
19  35.36764   0.00000
20  32.69343   0.00000
21  34.89597   0.00000
22  45.05710   0.00000
23  52.12515   0.00000
24  56.68825   0.10399
25  42.82138   2.70632
26  43.87267   9.75719
27  40.92407  17.95513
28  48.11841  21.02564
29  48.36029  31.34945
30  39.96910  69.62344
31  41.95327  63.31533
32  48.08798 111.20725
33  35.59892  82.59722
34  27.07698 209.27335
35  31.77831 192.61394
36  31.61700 298.17208
37  20.90314 353.80105
38  14.74480 322.15964
39  15.83181 326.86597
40  20.77642 409.25021
41   2.65196 370.75941
42   7.51343 396.27318
43   2.72389 386.30825
44   5.08969 468.23395
45   5.57108 456.78302
46   4.05819 418.21052
47   0.16106 376.49471
48   1.27724 332.54223
49   1.25692 264.52353
50   1.25692 198.16843
51   0.00000 0.00000
52   0.00000 186.77477
53   0.00000 208.19134
54   3.68738 171.52916
55   0.00000 127.77642
56   8.80174 157.18997
60   0.00000 0.00000
61   0.00000 0.00000
```

Comment: What's the expected output? (And - with respect to your ex. data - why?)

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771343/conditional-calculating-maximum-value-in-the-column); it outlines a number of approaches concerned with conditional identifying of maximum rows.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use smwrBase::eventNum from [github](https://github.com/USGS-R). The below will return t4a with just the last records with D & L ==0. Then you just pick up the first record (i.e., t4a[1](https://github.com/USGS-R)) to get the record after the last non-zero entry.

```
library(smwrBase) # from https://github.com/USGS-R
t4a<-t4[smwrBase::eventNum(t4$D==0 & t4$L==0, reset=TRUE)==
         max(smwrBase::eventNum(t4$D==0 & t4$L==0, reset=TRUE)),]
```